# Reading Open Source: a series of IIFEs

Tags: javascript, open-source, iife

I've been reading the Medium.js [Open Source Project](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Medium.js/blob/master/medium.js) that tries to mock Medium.com.

While reading, I noticed a pattern in the code. Mainly, an IIFE is called every so often to do a variety of stuff.

```
(function(Medium) {
      "use strict";
      //do stuff  
})(Medium);
(function(Medium) {
     "use strict";
     //do stuff
})(Medium);
(function(Medium) {
     "use strict";
     //do stuff

etc.
```

Why is the code compartmentalized like this? Couldn't it all be invoked at the same time, why call a series of IFFE statements? Is this a common pattern? You can view my link above for the full code I am referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through [the source files](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Medium.js/tree/master/src/Medium), you will see that each individual component is developed in a separate JavaScript file. [A build script](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Medium.js/blob/master/build) is used to concatenate all of these scripts together, and produce the file you are looking at.

By developing it this way, you could build your own custom build with only the components you need. By wrapping groups of functions together in an IIFE, he can also avoid setting `"use strict"` globally, and for each individual function. If there was a need to a variable to be shaded between a set of API's, this allows a variable to be declared inside the IIFE, without colliding with variables in other modules or the global space.

But the main advantage is the developer can develop the library as multiple different files, and you can optionally only include those you need in your project.

Comment: I see. So is making component parts and then a build file to combine it all together a common way of building projects? Or is this unique to this project?

Comment: @ApathyBear It's fairly common, with simplicity being the main advantage to this option. There are alternative to this method such as the CommonJS syntax which can be compiled together with 3rd-party wrappers. jQuery uses a RequireJS-based build script to compile their library. D3.js uses smash.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the `src/Medium` directory you can see that each of these IIFE's are separate files and many of them have matching files in the `tests` directory.

They separate their code like this so they can split their code up into small testable modules and they use IIFE's to extend an existin Medium object with new functionality.

The `Medium.js` file is a result of a build process that concatinates all the files in the `src/Medium` folder.